# How to get all posts related to a term with WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

I want to get all french brands.

When I try with post type brand, it works (for example it returns 1000 results).

```
wp post list --post_type=brand
```

If I add a parameter: taxonomy term (`--<taxonomy>=term_slug`)

```
wp post list --post_type=brand --origin=france
```

or

```
wp post list --post_type=brand --season=winter
```

It still returns same quantity of results (1000 results).

I can't read it in [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/) but this [closed issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1491) says it's possible.

Is it possible... or was it possible before and not now?

Comment: Is `origin` and `season` the correct name for the taxonomy and is it linked to your post type? I just tried `wp post list --post_type=product --product_cat=Foo` (Foo being a product category) and it worked.